# Sending an email with python to phone

Tags: python, email, sms

I'm trying to make a script to send a text message to myself. The At&t gateway is `number@txt.att.net` so that is what I'm using as my `to` address. So here's my code:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.smtp('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.login("MINE@gmail.com", "PASS12345")

msg = "\nHello!" 
server.sendmail("MINE@gmail.com", "0000000000@txt.att.net", msg)
```

My number is subbed with the 0's and my email address is subbed with MINE. However, even as simple of a script this it is, it's not working. I'm getting the error:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'smtp'`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I know it says it doesn't have the attribute, but all the examples I've seen use this syntax. I'm using 3.3 if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive.   The class name is SMTP. However, you'll need to use starttls, gmail will not allow you to authenticate insecurely.

Comment: I first used `SMTP` but it gave the same error so that is why it's in lower case.

Comment: Grr, Can't format code very well in comments, but `import smtplib` then `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) works just fine on the command line of my Python3.2 interpreter.